# Piping to mail results in new lines instead of overwritten lines

Tags: pipe

We are running maldet on several servers and we pipe the output of the cronjobs to a mail address to check the results. For 9 servers this works well but with the 10th server the output is different.

Normally we get the last output of the screen but with the problem server we get every line of the output. Maldet rewrites 1 line for every file it scanned so the return to the beginning of the line on the screen is outputted to a new line in the mail.

2 examples:

### Good:

```
maldet(30251): {scan} setting nice scheduler priorities for all operations: cpunice 19 , ionice 6
maldet(30251): {scan} file list completed in 172s, found 3850 files...
maldet(30251): {scan} found clamav binary at /usr/bin/clamscan, using clamav scanner engine...
maldet(30251): {scan} scan of / (3850 files) in progress...

**maldet(30251): {scan} scan completed on /: files 3850, malware hits 0, cleaned hits 0, time 316s** maldet(30251): {scan} scan report saved, to view run: maldet --report 160707-0016.30251
```

### BAD:

```
maldet(2198): {scan} 3577/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3578/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3579/3587 files 
scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3580/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3581/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3582/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 
cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3583/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3584/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3585/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet
(2198): {scan} 3586/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned[1Gmaldet(2198): {scan} 3587/3587 files scanned: 0 hits 0 cleaned
maldet(2198): {scan} scan completed on /: files 3587, malware hits 0, cleaned hits 0, time 654s
maldet(2198): {scan} scan report saved, to view run: maldet --report 160707-0045.2198
```

As you can see every file is mentioned in the output. But only when redirecting to mail. Not on the screen.

We are running 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

Comment: the bad maldet is probably configured for verbose output in the configuration file, and you are seeing a progress report updated all on one line. (To see the same on the screen pipe the maldet command into `cat -v`).

Comment: No difference in maldet configuration. Problem seems to be that a CR is piped into a CR with New line
Cat -v will show the CR as new lines as far as I understand. I don't want the new lines. :(

Answer (score 1):

When writing to screen, the CR character causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the line, causing the following characters to overwrite what was previously there. However, maldet should use this mechanism (and the control codes visible in your example) only when writing to a terminal. The real question is why maldet on that odd server thinks that its output is a screen and not a pipe.